# Mac App Store Won't Open on Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, macos

For the past few weeks my Mac App Store hasn't been loading correctly. Occasionally it does, but i'd say this has only been once or twice in the last month.

Here's a link of what it looks like:

[image]

Alternatively, anyone now how I can install Yosemite without going into the App Store?

Comment: Is this on genuine apple hardware?  I've seen this behavior on VMs where the serial number was set by VMware to longer than 12 characters.

Answer (score 1):

First, close the app store or itunes, etc.  I fixed this by opening a terminal, then getting a super user terminal:
sudo su -
enter your password
now be careful. You are root.

Next we want to kill all the App Store related processes.  This doesn't hurt anything.  Let's find them using the ps command and then using the grep search utility to get down to what we want.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ root# ps -ef |grep store |grep -vi google
  501  9284     1   0 21Dec15 ??         0:08.90 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeassetd
  501  9349     1   0 21Dec15 ??         0:00.73 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storeinappd
  501  9353     1   0 21Dec15 ??         0:01.91 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storedownloadd
  501  9459     1   0 21Dec15 ??         0:00.17 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/storelegacy
```

The second column is the process ID we want.  We want to use the kill command:

```
kill 9284 9349 9353 9459
```

The numbers will be different on your PC.  Open up app store and it should work!
I have also read other ways - removing some verisign keys from the key chain app, and others, but this is what fixed me.